# Why an i getting a TypeError returning a string

Tags: javascript, string

```
function toCamelCase(str){
    let word = str.split("-").toUpperCase().join()
    return word;
}
```

> TypeError: str.split(...).toUpperCase is not a function

Comment: You are calling a string method on an array. You should use map.

Comment: or, more simply, swap the order of toUpperCase and split - because either way you're doing it wrong

Comment: @Bravo that would prevent the error, but the result would probably not be what the OP wants – they want to convert the string to camel case

Comment: I know ... they want `.replace(/-(.)/g, (_, c) => c.toUpperCase())`

Comment: .split() make an array of strings ["a","b","c"] and .toUpperCase() is a method to uppercase strings not arrays ( "this is a sample".toUpperCase() => This Is A Sample ) this is why you get this error

Answer (score 2):

`str.split("-")` returns an array and arrays dont have `toUpperCase()` method. You can use `map()` to loop thru each element. Since you want to `toCamelCase` the string you can  `toUpperCase()` the first character. Use `join("")` with empty string parameter to join the array.

```js
function toCamelCase(str) {
  let word = str.split("-").map(o=> o[0].toUpperCase() + o.slice(1) ).join("");
  return word;
}

console.log( toCamelCase( "hello-world" ) );
```